# Bad File Descriptor and my file output becomes locked (I am not able to access the files created by my code)

Tags: c, file-descriptor, dup2

So I'm having a problem outputting terminal command output into a file. My assignment is to create a program that uses fork for every command in a given text file and run said command using execvp(). In my code (specifically my child process, which I have commented in my code) I used open() to create the files and used dup2() to output the command line outputs into a file. My problem is that I get the error: "write error: bad file descriptor." The file I am using to test my program contains the following shell commands

```
sleep 5
ls -latr
sleep 3
pwd
sleep 1
wc /etc/passwd
```

The program runs fine for the sleep commands, but doesn't work for the others. The program also creates a .out file that I am not able to access.

[Here is a picture of the files I can't access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Qv4.jpg)

[Here is a screenshot of the output if I run the program in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT9A4.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    #include <unistd.h>

    #include <fcntl.h>

    #include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

FILE* myfile = fopen(argv[1],"r"); //opens file 

    if(myfile == NULL)

    {

        printf("Error file is null");

    }



    //separate each line of the file into a command

    char commands[100][1000]; //Contains the commands of the file. Max array of size of 100 commands and 1000 chars per command

    char line [128];

    int i = 0; //iterator, counts total amount of lines/commands

    while (fgets(line,sizeof line,myfile) != NULL) /* read a line */

    {

        strcpy(commands[i], line); /* write the line */

        i++;

    }



    //Parse commands to be readable by execvp by using strtok

    char *arguments[100][(1000/2)+1]; //max of 501 arguments, will be used for execvp()

for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)

    {

        commands[k][strlen(commands[k])-1] = '\0';

        arguments[k][0] = strtok(commands[k], " ");

        int l = 0; //iterator

        while(arguments[k][l] != NULL)

        {

                arguments[k][++l] = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }

    }



    pid_t pids[i]; //create process pid array of size [total commands in the file]



    //for loop runs i amount of times, i == total commands

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)

{

        pids[j] = fork();



        //If fork fails, exit

    if((pids[j]  < 0))

    {

        printf("An error occured creating the fork \n");

        return 2;

    }



    //This is the Child Processes

    else if(pids[j] == 0)

    {

                if(myfile == NULL)

        {

            printf("\n Error! File is NULL... \n");

        }

                else

                {   

                    char outBuffer[50];

                    char errBuffer[50];

                    pid_t childPID = getpid();

                    pid_t parentPID = getppid();

            

                    sprintf(outBuffer, "%d.out",childPID);

                    sprintf(errBuffer, "%d.err",parentPID);

            

                    int outFile = open(outBuffer, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | 0777);

                    int errFile = open(errBuffer, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | 0777);

                    if (outFile < 0 || errFile < 0)

                    {

                        printf("Error with opening the out/err file");

                    }

            

                    dup2(outFile,1);

                    dup2(errFile,2);



                    close(errFile);

                    close(outFile);



                    printf("Starting command %d: child %d pid of parent %d \n",j+1,childPID,parentPID);

                    int err = execvp(arguments[j][0],arguments[j]);

                    if(err == -1)

                    {

                        printf("Could not find the given program to execute \n");

                            return 2;

                    }

                    printf("Finished child %d pid of parent %d \n",childPID,parentPID);    

                }

        }

    }



    fclose(myfile);

    //This is the parent process

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)

{

        int wstatus;



    wait(&wstatus);

        if(WIFEXITED(wstatus))

        {

                int statusCode = WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);

                if(statusCode == 0)

                {

                    printf("Successful execution! \n");

                }

                else

                {

                    printf("Exited with exit code: %d \n", statusCode);

                }

        

        }

}



    return 0;
```

}

Comment: That's a lot to scroll through, it would be great if you could remove the excess amounts of whitespace and fix your indentation in certain areas.

Comment: It would help if you clarify your question - it appears that you _are_ able to succesfully run each command from the input file, and it also appears that you're creating `.out` files for each command run. Are you specifically asking about why the `.out` files have locked-down permissions?